# How to make Parsley custom validation depending on select

Tags: parsley.js

I want to know how to make custom validation with Parsley like below case.

```
<select name="salary_type" class="form-control" id="id_salary_type">
    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
    <option value="4">option4</option>
    <option value="5">option5</option>
    <option value="6">option6</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="salary" class="form-control" value="None" step="0.25" data-parsley-errors-container="#salary-errors" id="id_salary">

<div class="errors-box">
    <div id="salary-errors"></div>
</div>
```

I want to show error messages if input salary is empty and when selected option is option1 or option2.
[image]
However, I don't want to show error message when user selected --- or option3 or option4 or option5 or option6 and submit.

Help me, please.

Comment: Did you check out [this demo](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html)?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to implement in my case.